# Is there any rails/ruby functions that I can use to reset a hash lookup table every 24 hours or at a specific date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok so I have an app that allows users to pull App Store data, specifically top free top paid etc. The various attributes are quite limited, but users can filter by category and country. So obviously this leads to a lot of repeated queries, now normally this wouldn't be a problem, but I also use this data with google api which has a credits system. So What I want to do is save these results in my database if the results are unique. I have this all set up and fine but my only hang up is how I determine if a query has been made before, so my solution is to make a hashtable that stores all queries that have been made before and if not NULL(nil) then I call the api to fetch the data then create a new record.

Issue is the App Store refreshes every day or so(not exactly sure the schedule but will look it up later). I would like to have this Hashtable reference function refresh or reset itself to all NULL at this interval.

What would be the most efficient or simple way to start a refresh for this? Additionally I am kinda new to rails, so where should I place this function? In the helper modules? Controller?

Thanks!

Edit:

ok so here is my HashTable helper module

```
module MapsHelper
    queryHistoryLookUp = {}
    i = 0
    31.times do |i|
        queryTableLookup.merge!(i =>[] ) 
    end

    def queryTableLookup(asciiNum, queryString)
        if queryTableLookup[asciiNum % 31].size == 0
            queryTableLookup[asciiNum % 31].push(queryString)
        else
        a = queryTableLookup[asciiNum % 31].size
        arrayOfQueries = queryTableLookup[asciiNum % 31]
        a.times do |i|
            if arrayOfQueries[i] == queryString
                return true
            else
                return false
            end
        end
    end
end

end
def queryHash(query)
    asciSum = 0
    query.each_char do |i|
        asciSum += i.sum 
    end
    queryTableLookup(asciSum, query)
end
```

end

additionally I am kinda new to rails, can I interact with these functions using Javascript, since on the client side I create the string query.

Comment: Look into using a rake task. You can leverage gems like Whenever to run a cron job to perform arbitrary functions for you on a regular basis.

Comment: @MarsAtomic , do you think I should add the above code into my model instead of my helper?

Comment: A general rule of thumb is that you want your logic in your models. That logic can be called from your controllers, but the logic itself should be written in the model. That said, the real answer is that you should do some reading on [rake tasks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks), which would put the logic in your lib/tasks directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, your best bet would be to use the Rails cache system.  It provides a method of caching data, with an optional `expires_in` time.

From the docs:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.get_api_data(key)
    Rails.cache.fetch("my_model/api_data:#{key}", expires_in: 12.hours) do
      SomeService::API.get_data(key)
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your hash (which I think it could exist in a class variable) you can store both the query and the last access datetime:

Suppose you have a hash as class variable to the Foo class with name `cache` and that the `query` variable is your current query that you want to check.

`if Foo.cache[query].nil? || (DateTime.now - Foo.cache[query].last_fetch).to_i > 0
   results = your_method_to_fetch_data_for(query)
   Foo.cache[query] = {:results => results, :last_fetch => Datetime.now}
 else
   results = Foo.cache[query][:results]
 end`